# How to generate lookup table from expression

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, image-processing

There is a [Research paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-020-09182-0) on image encryption based on finite algebraic structures.
They gave following method to generate lookup table ( also known as S-box).

S-box which is used in the proposed approach is based on the action of general linear group
$GL(2,\mathbb F_{2^8})$ on finite field $\mathbb F_{2^8}$ of order 256.

w:$GL(2,\mathbb F_{2^8})$× ${\mathbb {F} _{2^8}} \to {\mathbb {F} _{2^8}}$

w(M,y)= $F_M(y)$

where $F_M(y)=\frac{\alpha(y)+\beta}{\gamma(y)+\delta} $ and $\alpha ,\ \beta ,\ \gamma\ and\ \delta$ are the elements of $\mathbb F_{2^8}$. $F_M$ is a bijective mapping from $\mathbb F_{2^8}$ to $\mathbb F_{2^8}$, and the resultant values of $F_M$ are then converted into a 16x16 lookup table, which is the required S-box.

I have not studied group theory, so after doing some research on internet I was able to understand some of it. But I still don't understand how will I get the final lookup table.
I am having difficulty understanding what is $\alpha ,\ \beta ,\ \gamma\ and\ \delta$ here.

Any help would be appreciated, even if you know some source from where I can get started.

Comment: The group $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{2^8})$ is the group of $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices with coefficients from the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$. From this we can write an element of this general linear group $A \in \operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{2^8})$ as $A = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}$ with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{F}_{2^8}$ satisfying $\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma \ne 0$. From here you can get a bijective fractional linear transformation of the form $F_M(y)$ as you've written exactly because $\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma \ne 0$.

Comment: Can you show me an example on one or two values on how to get the lookup table?

Comment: Well if $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then the corresponding function $F_A(y) = \frac{1\cdot y + 0}{0\cdot y + 1} = y$ and the lookup table is just pairs $(y,F_A(y)) = (y,y)$. For general matrices $A = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{2^8})$, what you do is create a list $(y,x)$ where $x = F_A(x) = \frac{\alpha y + \beta}{\gamma y + \delta}$, i.e., the table is just the table of inputs/outputs for the function $F_A$.

Comment: Thanks. That made things clear.